# Auto Move Specific Data from Google Form Response after Submission of Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Google form which is linked to Form Response Sheet. I want to Move data from "Discrepency Report - Outlet" to "Vaishali Nagar - DTR" Sheet on each day after one submit the Google Form.

I am using script which is mentioned below the Question. The problem I am facing it runs on specific date.

Link of Spreadsheet is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MhCdwFscPqskeeM2Hza-t2VXoVkI6sq3XRCNybMm4NM/edit?usp=sharing

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Discrepency Report - Outlet'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('I:I');
  var testvalue = (testrange.setNumberFormat("@").getValues());
  Logger.log(testvalue);
  var ds = ss.getSheetByName('Vaishali Nagar - DTR'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  var dt = new Date();
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-0', 'dd/MM/yyyy')

  //Condition to check in I:I, if true, copy the same row to data array 
  for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i] == today) {
    data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,8).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to B
    j.push(i);
}  
}
  //Copy data array to destination sheet
  
  var start_row=ds.getRange('B7:B').getValues().filter(String).length +6; //calculate max row

  ds.getRange(start_row+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand "The problem I am facing it runs on specific date.". What do you mean? What is the problem with your script? Try to put an example in this form: the input and the desired output.

Comment: When you mention a specific date, what do you mean by that? Do you mean any time-based trigger for the function `copyrange()` that runs on a specific date? Or...do you mean the function only chooses certain date entries to copy the data from the given range?

Comment: I have added trigger which runs daily and data related to today's date is only moved.

Comment: You can you can’t compare date objects with the equal operator unless you convert them to numeric values or strings. Consult JavaScript Date() reference

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

`.getValues()` method returns a multidimensional array which indexes are respectively `values[column][row]`.

When looping through this array you will have to keep this in mind, especially when you build if-else blocks:

```
  for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {

// -------------------------
// Let's focus on this


    if (testvalue[i] == today) {  // -> [ 'dateString' ] == 'dateString'


// Even if 'dateString' is the same,
// it won't never be true because testValue[i] is an array.
// --------------------------

    data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,8).getValues());
    j.push(i);
}
```

### Solution

In this case since you are looping through the same column's rows you can just use the 0 index to access the correct 'dateString' value:

```
if (testvalue[0][i] == today) {  // -> [ 'dateString' ] == 'dateString'
```

Otherwise you will have to loop through the columns and build a nested for-loop for the rows.

### Reference

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Can you please help me with script for Today -1. where I will set the trigger. for Ex. If i run this script today then it should pick data of tomorrow only.

Comment: To get tomorrow date you just have to add 1 to the today Date object, to get yesterday subtract 1.
```
const today = new Date()
const tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
```

Comment: Can you please help me with script for Today -1. where I will set the trigger. for Ex. If i run this script today then it should pick data of yesterday only. I have set the Date in "I Colum" of Discrepancy Report - Outlet Sheet. If I run this script today, then it should pick data of yesterday.

Comment: What error is it showing? Please update your question with your current code and the error stack trace.